# How to add a lib file reference to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've got a C# project in Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to add a reference to some 3rd party C code where I have a dll and lib files on my computer.  The C code is Win API native code.

I have attempted to add the dll as a reference to the project, but I get a "A reference to "code.dll" could not be added Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component." Some research has made me think that I need to add the lib file as a reference in the project, but when I browse for a reference in Visual Studio 2012, it only searches for dll, tlb, olb, ocx, exe, and manifest files. It seems like in the past you could add a lib file to a Visual Studio project, but it seems to be different in VS 2012.

Does anyone know how to add a lib reference to a project in VS 2012? Or am I wrong altogether here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. What you CAN do, however, is to add a C++/CLI assembly to your solution, and from there you can link to the Lib file (and include the C headers files which you propably have as well).

The other option you have is to P/Invoke to the DLL. Then you have to figure out how to write a proper declaration for each function in the DLL.